# Is there any use for a binary search tree that is not self-balanced?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-balancing

All of the types of binary search trees I can find are self-balancing. Are there any that aren't, that are actually useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example that comes to my mind is a [Rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29), a binary tree that is used to store and edit efficiently long strings, such as in text editors.

It is not balanced *per se*, but Concatenation and Split require the tree to be balanced. But every character can be accessed `O(log N)` even in unbalanced trees, so maybe this fits your question

Answer (score 0):

*Every* Binary Search Tree that does not *actively* perform balancing may become unbalanced.

In particular, inserting a (reverse) sorted sequence into a BST will lead to a degenerate tree (essentially a linked list):

```
3 2 1

    3
   /
  2
 /
1
```

and

```
1 2 3

1
 \
  2
   \
    3
```

Comment: My question was confusing, so I edited it a bit. Your point is well taken. So are you saying that all binary search trees self-balance?

Comment: No, I am saying that *only* self-balancing binary search trees self-balance, and I give an example in my answer of how a binary search tree becomes unbalanced, if it is not actively balanced.

Comment: Is there any use for a binary search tree that is not self-balanced?